# How can I kill an unresponsive query in Valentina Studio (for PostgreSQL)?

Tags: postgresql, valentina-studio

Is there a way to kill a slow or unresponsive query in Valentina Studio as there is in MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 3):

this feature was added for MySQL into v7.1.4 at 17 May 2017. Now SQL Editor has button Cancel.

It uses this or that technique, which provides this or that DBMS for this task.

Answer (score 1):

As of http://www.valentina-db.com/bt/view.php?id=7685 I think there is no such feature.

I'm also searching for this. 
I'm using Valentina Studio 6.6.9 on MacOS with PostgreSQL 9.5.3.

My actual solution is to use pgadmin in parallel to see my query started by Valentina Studio in pgadmin's server status monitoring. I can request to kill it there.

I have to say: Yes that sucks! Sorry about that but its the truth.